# Prefabs of mobs in the game on Unity do not go on the phone

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

There was a very interesting error with game characters, on the first level they walk quietly and everything is OK, and on the second they go only in the editor, and after compilation they are no longer there. Ai navigation exists. The character must find ... by the tag maybe he is on stage. What could be the problem? error only at the second level and only after assembly
mob script(They do not go, they do not attack if you approach. So either they don’t see or an error in the script on the phone occurs)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class EmenScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Animator animator;
    public GameObject zombieObject;
    private Transform player;
    private float curr_time;
    private int xp = 100;
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        StartCoroutine(findPath());
        StartCoroutine(playerDetected());
        curr_time = 0f;
    }
    public void damage()
    {
        if(xp == 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Find("Xp/Cube/").gameObject.active = false;
            StopAllCoroutines();
            agent.enabled = false;
            animator.SetTrigger("death");
            Destroy(zombieObject, 30f);
        } else {
            xp = xp > 15 ? xp - 15 : 0;
            Transform xpp = gameObject.transform.Find("Xp/Cube/XpLine").transform;
            xpp.localScale = new Vector3(xpp.localScale.x, xpp.localScale.y, xp / 100f);
            xpp.localPosition = new Vector3(xpp.localPosition.x, xpp.localPosition.y, (0.97f - xpp.localScale.z) / 2);
        }
    }
    public void damageFull()
    {
        gameObject.transform.Find("Xp/Cube").gameObject.active = false;
        StopAllCoroutines();
        agent.enabled = false;
        animator.SetTrigger("death");
        Destroy(zombieObject, 30f);
    }

    IEnumerator playerDetected()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(player == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(player.GetComponent<UserController>().xp <= 0)
            {
                agent.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = true;
                animator.SetBool("walk", false);
            }
            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < 1.2f)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("attack");
                curr_time -= Time.deltaTime;
                if(curr_time <= 0)
                {
                    if(player.GetComponent<UserController>().xp - 25 > 0)
                    {
                        player.GetComponent<UserController>().xp -= 25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        player.GetComponent<UserController>().xp = 0;
                    }
                    curr_time = 0.5f;
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
        }
    }
    IEnumerator findPath()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(player.GetComponent<UserController>().xp > 0)
            {
               
                if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < 40f)
                {
                    animator.SetBool("walk", true);
                    if(player && agent.isActiveAndEnabled)
                    {
                        agent.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = false;
                        agent.SetDestination(player.position);
                    }
                } else {
                    agent.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = true;
                    animator.SetBool("walk", false);       
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the first level and second level's picture?

Answer (score 0):

I think error must be about scene change but I need to see script and lvl's.

Comment: As it turned out for some reason, the distance to the character is greater than at the first level, although prefabs are used